# Rstudio - how to write smaller code

Tags: r

I'm brand new to programming and an picking up Rstudio as a stats tool.
I have a dataset which includes multiple questionnaires divided by weeks, and I'm trying to organize the data into meaningful chunks.
Right now this is what my code looks like:

> w1a=table(qwest1,talm1)
>
> w2a=table(qwest2,talm2)
>
> w3a=table(quest3,talm3)

Where quest and talm are the names of the variable and the number denotes the week.
Is there a way to compress all those lines into one line of code so that I could make w1a,w2a,w3a... each their own object with the corresponding questionnaire added in?

Thank you for your help, I'm very new to coding and I don't know the etiquette or all the vocabulary.

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if we had a better idea of how the data looked. Please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then come back and edit your question. Other suggested reading: [minimal, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/). (Also, RStudio is an interface, "R" is the stats tool. This question is about the language, not the interface, so I'm removing the `[rstudio]` tag.)

Comment: Having numbers in your variable names is a sign that things are already off to a bad start. Related values should all be in lists in R, rather than be variables with kind of similar names. How are you creating them in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you wanted (but not what you asked for):

```
 tbl_list <- mapply(table,  list(qwest1, qwest2, quest3),
                            list(talm1, talm2, talm3) )
 names(tbl_list) <-  c('w1a', 'w2a','w3a')
```

You are committing a fairly typical new-R-user error in creating multiple similarly named and structured objects but not putting them in a list. This is my effort at pushing you in that direction. Could also have been done via:

```
  qwest_lst <-  list(qwest1, qwest2, quest3)
  talm_lst <- list(talm1, talm2, talm3)
  tbl_lst <- mapply(table, qwest_lst, talm_lst)
  names(tbl_list) <-  paste0('w', 1:3, 'a')
```

There are other ways to programmatically access objects with character vectors using `get` or `wget`.

Comment: for `dplyr` users, the function `lst` behaves just like `list` except that it names its items using the object names, which I've found very convenient.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, it did what I needed to do. I never knew of the mapply or the names function. I appreciate your help and the education.

Comment: `mapply` lets you work through lists like they were "parallel" columns. First argument is a function and the rest of the arguments get either positionally matched or matched by name to the arguments of that function.